# How do you use DataView's RowFilter using keyword 'IN' to filter collection

Tags: c#, dataview, rowfilter

I would like to filter a collection populated in a DataView. The control I am using for this is a multi-select checkbox Combobox. The string returned from this is 'val1, val2, val3'. I then pass this to a sql query statement so as to be able to use as my FilterExpression. However,when assigning my expression to dataView.RowFilter = somethingFilterString which has my expression as Something IN (val1, val2, val3) is gives an error that it cannot find column val1. Anyone that can help please????

Comment: I'm guessing you're comparing strings -- have you put quotes around `val1` (`'val1'`)?

Answer (score 0):

If the values of `val1, val2, val3` are strings (eg, `"apples, pears, bananas"`), then you need the query text to show they are strings otherwise it has to assume they are column names.

If you're building the comma-separated list like so:

```
var csv = string.Join(",", comboBox.SelectedValues); //guess on combo box property
```

... then you could do something like this to get the values with quotes instead:

```
[Test]
public void SO6680770()
{
    var cols = new[] { "apples", "pears", "bananas" };

    var csv = string.Join(", ", cols.Select(s => string.Concat("'", s, "'")));

    Assert.AreEqual("'apples', 'pears', 'bananas'", csv);
}
```